# MVC3 Validation Error Message in Tooltip

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to ASP.NET and MVC3. I have got a project where the MVC3 Validation Error Message needs to be shown in Tooltip without updating jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js.
I have tried this

[click here](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/07/13/overriding-unobtrusive-client-side-validation-settings-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx)

But could not get it to work. Here is the function the I should be using according to the link above. It says do something here...I could not figure out what code I should write to show the error message with  a error icon beside the required field when validation fails.

```
$(function() {
    var settngs = $.data($('form')[0], 'validator').settings;
    var oldErrorFunction = settngs.errorPlacement;
    var oldSucessFunction = settngs.success;
    settngs.errorPlacement = function (error, inputElement) {
        //Do something here
        oldErrorFunction(error, inputElement);
    }
    settngs.success = function (error) {
        //Do something here
        oldSucessFunction(error);
    }
});
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following css,

```
.myfield-validation-error
{
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    background-image:url(../../Images/Close-2-icon.png);
}
.myfield-validation-valid
{
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    background-image:url(../../Images/Ok-icon.png);
}
```

Then you can make use your these classes on your success and failure callback,

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var settngs = $.data($('form')[0], 'validator').settings;
        var oldErrorFunction = settngs.errorPlacement;
        var oldSucessFunction = settngs.success;
        settngs.errorPlacement = function (error, inputElement) {
            $(inputElement).closest('div').next().removeClass('myfield-validation-valid').addClass('myfield-validation-error')
            oldErrorFunction(error, inputElement);
        }
        settngs.success = function (error) {
            $(error).closest('div').addClass('myfield-validation-valid').removeClass('myfield-validation-error')
            oldSucessFunction(error);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Further check [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1716641.aspx/1?MVC%203%20Validation%20Problem) link.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MVC3, you can leverage the validation provided. Take a look at the Account Controller - Register View for an example of how to implement it.

Research (in View):

> @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Account creation was unsuccessful.
>   Please correct the errors and try again.")

and the Class for:

> System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute